# How can I turn off caching in HTTP redirections in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I use *node-formidable* to process a form via POST at `http://127.0.0.1/upload`.  After processing, I want to redirect the user to `http://127.0.0.1/`.  Currently, I need to reload `http://127.0.0.1/` in order to see the uploaded data.  I assume I need to tweak a cache setting.

How can I do this in Node.js?  Do I set `Cache-Control: no-cache` on `http://127.0.0.1/` or `/upload`?

Answer (score 11):

you set it on `http://127.0.0.1`.

try something like this:

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```